# How to Filter an array of objects by multiple conditions using ES2016?

Tags: javascript

```
// all products
let products = [
  { name: "A", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, pattern: {'id': 'PLAID'}, size: 50 },
  { name: "B", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, pattern: {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}, size: 60 },
  { name: "C", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, pattern: {'id': 'SOLID'}, size: 100 },
  { name: "D", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, pattern: {'id': 'PLAID'}, size: 70 },
  { name: "E", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, pattern: {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}, size: 80 },
  { name: "F", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, pattern: {'id': 'SOLID'}, size: 100 },
  { name: "G", fabricColor: {"id": 'GREEN'}, pattern: {'id': 'PLAID'}, size: 90 },
  { name: "H", fabricColor: {"id": 'GREEN'}, pattern: {'id': 'SOLID'}, size: 100 },
  { name: "I", fabricColor: {"id": 'GREEN'}, pattern: {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}, size: 80 }
];

// filters applied
let filters = {
  fabricColor: [{"id": 'BLUE'}, {"id": 'BLACK'}],
  pattern: [{'id': 'PLAID'}, {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}]
};


var filtered = multiFilter(products, filters);


/**
 * Multi-filter an array of objects
 * @param  {Array}  array  : list of elements to apply a multiple criteria filter
 * @param  {Object} filters: Contains multiple criteria filters by the property names of the objects to filter
 * @return {Array}
 */
function multiFilter(array, filters) {
  let filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  // filters all elements passing the criteria
  let filterData = array.filter((item) => filterKeys.every((key) => (filters[key].indexOf(item[key]) !== -1)));
  return filterData
}



 // expected result 
let expected = [
  { name: "A", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, pattern: {'id': 'PLAID'}, size: 50 },
  { name: "B", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, pattern: {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}, size: 60 },
  { name: "D", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, pattern: {'id': 'PLAID'}, size: 70 },
  { name: "E", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, pattern: {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}, size: 80 }
];
```

I tried with above code but not able to filter according to filter condition . The filter result should match with expected result .

Little help or any reference highly appreciated.

Comment: whats d  expected result?

Comment: let expected = [
  { name: "A", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, pattern: {'id': 'PLAID'}, size: 50 },
  { name: "B", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, pattern: {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}, size: 60 },
  { name: "D", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, pattern: {'id': 'PLAID'}, size: 70 },
  { name: "E", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, pattern: {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}, size: 80 }
];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `filter` your results like below

```js
let products = [
  { name: "A", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, pattern: {'id': 'PLAID'}, size: 50 },
  { name: "B", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, pattern: {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}, size: 60 },
  { name: "C", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, pattern: {'id': 'SOLID'}, size: 100 },
  { name: "D", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, pattern: {'id': 'PLAID'}, size: 70 },
  { name: "E", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, pattern: {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}, size: 80 },
  { name: "F", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, pattern: {'id': 'SOLID'}, size: 100 },
  { name: "G", fabricColor: {"id": 'GREEN'}, pattern: {'id': 'PLAID'}, size: 90 },
  { name: "H", fabricColor: {"id": 'GREEN'}, pattern: {'id': 'SOLID'}, size: 100 },
  { name: "I", fabricColor: {"id": 'GREEN'}, pattern: {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}, size: 80 }
];

// filters applied
let filters = {
  fabricColor: [{"id": 'BLUE'}, {"id": 'BLACK'}],
  pattern: [{'id': 'PLAID'}, {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}]
};

let res = products.filter(d => Object.entries(filters).every(([k ,v]) => 
                                  Object.values(v).map(m => m.id).includes(d[k].id) ))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: What if we have different key for filter instead of id . Suppose in fabricColor have key colorId  and in pattern have patternId key. So how will you that condition??

Answer (score 1):

You can `reduce` the filters with the help of [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (where the returned accumulator is a filtered version of the old accumulator after applying one of the provided filters):

```js
function multiFilter(array, filters) {
  return Object.entries(filters).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    // for a product to qualify, it should match at least one of
    // the filters for this property "k"
    return acc.filter(a => v.some(f => f.id === a[k].id))
  }, array);
}


let products = [
  { name: "A", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, pattern: {'id': 'PLAID'}, size: 50 },
  { name: "B", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, pattern: {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}, size: 60 },
  { name: "C", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLUE'}, pattern: {'id': 'SOLID'}, size: 100 },
  { name: "D", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, pattern: {'id': 'PLAID'}, size: 70 },
  { name: "E", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, pattern: {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}, size: 80 },
  { name: "F", fabricColor: {"id": 'BLACK'}, pattern: {'id': 'SOLID'}, size: 100 },
  { name: "G", fabricColor: {"id": 'GREEN'}, pattern: {'id': 'PLAID'}, size: 90 },
  { name: "H", fabricColor: {"id": 'GREEN'}, pattern: {'id': 'SOLID'}, size: 100 },
  { name: "I", fabricColor: {"id": 'GREEN'}, pattern: {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}, size: 80 }
];

let filters = {
  fabricColor: [{"id": 'BLUE'}, {"id": 'BLACK'}],
  pattern: [{'id': 'PLAID'}, {'id': 'WINDOWPANE'}]
};

var filtered = multiFilter(products, filters);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: What if we have different key for filter instead of id . Suppose in fabricColor have key colorId  and in pattern have patternId key. So how will you that condition??